# Is Windows 7 better at handling mapped network drives than Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, samba, windows-xp, network-drive

I am looking for justifications to upgrade my workstation from Windows XP (SP3) to Windows 7.

Is Windows 7 better at handling mapped network drives than Windows XP?

I keep having issues with "drive already in use" and I really suspect it's the way XP handles networked drives.

The samba server I am mapping to is consistent and never changes.

On occasion XP will prompt some error with the drive.

Almost seemingly at random.

Comment: You should only get a "drive already in use" error if said drive is already mapped. Windows 7 will likely display the same behavior - it's expected for the system to not let you create a new drive if that letter is already being used.

Comment: Windows 7 is better, yes, but mapped drives are problematic from non-Microsoft shares in some cases, causing random messages like you're getting.

Comment: The fact that it isn't a 10 year old operating system that is no longer receiving upgrade support and isn't going to be compatible with software and drivers going forward isn't justification enough?  (To say nothing about improved performance and security.)